# Twitter login in react-native for both Android and iOS

Tags: react-native, twitter-login, react-native-ios

Has anyone integrated twitter login in react native application for both Android and iOS. Any help is highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think It will be useful for beginners,

1. Go to >https://apps.twitter.com/ site
2. Create New App
3. Fill the following

   -> APP NAME

   -> DESC

   -> WEBSITE (anything like >http://www.sometext.com)

   -> CALLBACK URLS (twittersdk://)

   -> AGREE DEV AGREEMENT

   -> CREATE YOUR TWITTER APPLICATION
4. Give permission for accessing email id
   So, open the created app

   -> go to SETTINGS tab and fill some url in privacy policy url and terms of service url

   -> click Update settings

   -> Go to PERMISSIONS tab

   -> under Additional Permissions click REQUEST EMAIL ADDREESSES FROM USERS

   -> click Update Settings
5. Under KEYS AND ACCESS TOKENS tab

   -> Get the consumer key and secret
6. Move to your project folder and give command as 'npm install react-native-twitter-signin --save'
7. For android setup give the command as 'react-native link react-native-twitter-signin'
8. move to 'urprojectfolder\node_modules\react-native-twitter-signin\android\src\main\java\com\goldenowl\twittersignin\TwitterSigninPackage.java' 
   and comment the line @Override before

   ```
   @Override
   public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
   return Collections.emptyList();
   }
   ```
9. Give command react-native link for linking react-native-vector-icons to your project.
10. Go to 'https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin'

    -> download this app

    -> move to Example folder

    -> get the TwitterButton.js file and paste it to ur app

    -> Import TwitterButton.js where u want and use it
11. When you press the LoginWithTwitter button in your app it will ask to enter username and password of twitter account and give authorize app permission.
12. The method _twitterSignIn in ur TwitterButton.js will access and print email,username,userId,name,authTokenSecret of your twitter account
13. Finally after login it will show logout button.(the method handleLogout will handle the logout functionality for that).

Answer (score 1):

Please always do a short research before posting a question. If you Google "react native twitter login", the first result is a module that seems to do what you are looking for:

[react-native-twitter-signin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-twitter-signin)

There are probaly more similar libraries out there.

Comment: i have shared the error which i am getting using react-native-twitter-signin

Comment: I am getting this error now
/home/ttnd/projects/rally-bus/node_modules/react-native-twitter-signin/android/src/main/java/com/goldenowl/twittersignin/TwitterSigninModule.java:32: error: TwitterSigninModule is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNewIntent(Intent) in ActivityEventListener
public class TwitterSigninModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ActivityEventListener {
       ^
1 error
:react-native-twitter-signin:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

Comment: Did you follow the instructions for setting it up? And did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project afterwards?

Comment: yes i did many times , i am using react-native version 0.31.0

Comment: Just run `cd android && ./gradlew clean` from your react native app directory. Should work